# Is there an FTP equivalent of Python's makedirs()?

Tags: python, ftp

I'm FTP'ing a pile of files with Python and some directory trees may not exist. Is there an FTP version of `makedirs()` available somewhere or will I have to build my own from scratch?

Comment: I can't find an implementation of this. It should be fairly easy to write such a function on your own, however, using iteration and `FTP.mkd` (assuming you use [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting this, I discovered a nifty little library, `ftputil` (http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net), that presents a different FTP interface that cribs as much of the `os` and `os.path` modules as possible. Using this, my final code went roughly like this:

```
import ftputil

host = ftputil.FTPHost(constants.FTP_HOST, constants.FTP_LOGIN, constants.FTP_PASS)
host.makedirs(path)
host.close()
```